# Make URL Request and read String

Tags: c++, string, http, url

first of all I'm aware of the fact that I'm not the first person to ask this, but I do need a different solution than libcurl.

What I want to do basically is make a HTTP request to a server and read the response into an std::string value (char* or CString would be fine as well).

libcurl is too big for my preference (I need to do static linking; I can't ship DLLs with my application and I'd like to keep it as small as possible, curl makes my app about 3M bigger).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: cURL and its library is *tiny* compared to many other. It also does just about one thing, and does it well, compared to other HTTP libraries which are part of larger (*much* larger) frameworks. The cURL library can also be built to a static library without problems, and the nice thing about modern linkers is that they don't pull in library code not used. The only way to get a smaller library would almost be to make one yourself, but then you have to be able to handle all the quirks and corner-cases of the HTTP.

Comment: Also, you mention `CString` which indicates you're using the MFC framework, which is *way* larger than cURL. It also indicates you're targeting Windows, and even on the smallest Windows phone systems a few MB is not very much these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and my solution was:

```
DeleteUrlCacheEntryA("http://example.com/file.txt");
DWORD state = URLDownloadToFileA(NULL, "http://example.com/file.txt", "file.txt", 0, NULL);
if (state != S_OK)
{
    // can not download...
    return;
}

std::ifstream file("file.txt");
std::string result((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
file.close();
DeleteFileA("file.txt");
```

It's a little bit inaccurate because of the temporary file, but it works for me and I hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration that you apparently target windows as platform, you can consider using the [windows http services api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It's not portable to other platforms, but it has the advantage of being built in.  MSDN provides lots of explanations and examples on [how to use it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).